# Are these too many options for a login screen?

Tags: login, signup-signon

Are these too many options for a login screen?

[image]

Should I try to find a way to present them in separated screens, or show hide different options with an animation?

I have the feeling that this screen could be too crowded but I couldn't say if it could be acceptable. Is there a rule of the thumb to follow in this situation?

Comment: Yup, it sure is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the login screen here at UX.stackexchange:

[image: login screen]

When you compare this with your mockup, yours looks crowded and a bit confusing. One of the reasons that the login screen feels overwhelming, is that you ask your users to make multiple choices at the same time:

1. Facebook or email
2. Log in or sign up (and what does connect mean? is that equivalent to logging in or signing up?)

The Sign up button is not completely clear - do I need to enter my desired email address + password in this screen, or will clicking the button lead to another form?

The stackexchange login on the other hand:

- treats **log in** as the primary option; signing up is possible as well but secondary
- does not explicitly mention a verb with the Google and Facebook options - it is already clear from the context that this is a log in screen
- uses colour and icons to support easy recognition of google and facebook
- uses both labels and sample values - a pattern such as you@example.org is easy to recognize

Answer (score 0):

The new trend is using apps without an account, so this should be the main option in big letters or just implicit by the workflow. The second smaller option is then called "secure data with an account" and you get to a screen where you can pick the options you have now.

Mariella is right for referencing the SE design, would even go so far to recommend the "login later" option you see when you post as guest.

[image]